# How to fix: The role binaries in your package are using an older version of the Windows Azure SDK

Tags: azure

My worker role is not working (local and cloud), and I have the suspicion it comes after I've upgraded to Azure SDK 2.2.

Even a bigger hint is the mesage in Output/General:

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: The role binaries in your package are using an older version of the Windows Azure SDK. Please consider upgrading.
```

But what do they refer with 'the binaries are using an older version of the SDK'. Are they referring to the References I use? Or is this a setting in the csproj, or Web/App.config?

I have the following references in my Worker role, that I think are related to Azure:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus                      2.2.0.0
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration      2.0.0.0
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime     2.2.0.0
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage            3.0.0.0
```

Is there any way to see the dll or 'version' mismatch between the SDK I am 'using' and the one they are expecting?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok maybe I should've seen this one coming: the version of the SDK that you are using is actually in the **.ccjproj** of your **Azure** project in the solution - so **not** the .csproj of your WebRole or WorkerRole.

If you open the **[Azure project].ccproj** in a text editor you will see a property called ProductVersion. I've set mine from 1.8 to 2.2 and everything starts working perfectly again.